# Iterating through multiple email bodies and pass to hash array

Tags: arrays, email, powershell, foreach, outlook

I am trying to iterate through emails, that have a specific subject line, and have the body of matching emails parsed and passed to a hash array.  There is an issue with how I am trying to deal with multiple email bodies that is causing an issue.

```psh
$ol=New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$ns=$ol.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
$inbox=$ns.GetDefaultFolder(6)
$Goodsubject='Interesting Email'
$mail = $InBox.items |
    Where-Object{
        $_.Unread -and $_.Subject -match  $Goodsubject
        #$_.Subject -match  $Goodsubject
    } | 
    Sort-Object ReceivedTime -Descending |
    Select-Object Subject,ReceivedTime,Body,SenderName
#    Select-Object Body
$mail | %{
    $_.Body | %{$interestinghash = @{}} {
        if ($_ -match "(.*): (.*)") {
            $interestinghash[$matches[1]]=$matches[2];
        }
    }
```

Assuming the email has 4 line, each with a key: value, and I look at `$interestinghash`, I will only have the a key value pair for a email.  I will not have all 4.  That said, I can replace the following line:

```psh
$mail | %{
    $_.Body | %{$interestinghash = @{}} {
        if ($_ -match "(.*): (.*)") {
            $interestinghash[$matches[1]]=$matches[2];
        }
    }
```

With:

```psh
$mail | %{$interestinghash = @{}} {
    if ($_ -match "(.*): (.*)") {
        $interestinghash[$matches[1]]=$matches[2];
    }
}
```

If I do this it will give me all 4 values but will only look at 1 email.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: You should split your block starting with `$mail` to lines, probably you have there a logical bracing error which you can easily discern when you add structure to the script block text.

Comment: you are resetting your hashtable for each email. Maybe you should put `$interestinghash = @{}` outside your foreach block

Comment: Use the [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662(v=office.15).aspx)/[FindNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862482(v=office.15).aspx) or [Restrict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Items class to get a collection of items that correspond to your conditions instead of using the Where-Object.